# Angular js and snapshot pages

Tags: angularjs

Have read up on angular and generating snapshots for the crawlers

Just want to know if the snapshot needs to have CSS or just plain and img tags for Facebook and Google etc. to work.

Any good examples of how to implement the framework with expression engine or Wordpress.

As I understand it you would actually create two versions of every page. Is that correctly understood ?

Cheers looking forward on trying it out . 
As I understand it it's enough to modify the  htaccess file to show the snapshots instead of the angular once when the request is coming from Facebook or Google etc.

Thanks

Comment: Didn't know it was so bad a question :) 
Anybody want to give a little headsup on the snapshots ?